How to return Row and Column header of a data in table
I am trying to find a function where I can return Row and Column Headers of a data from a table. I have attached a screenshot of a sample data table.

And below is the result I am working out.

Here's a link of the sample sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KTBM0T05MJtPFGUw_UoxWheksXv7vDKbCvzlZr7V_Yk/edit?usp=sharing
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you
I tried researching the internet and here as well. I have encountered index-query formula, but I haven't really been understanding it well. I have tried the common lookup functions.

try:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(B3:F7&"×"&A3:A7&"×"&B1:F1&"×"&B2:F2), "×"))


with open ranges:
=INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(FILTER(B3:F, A3:A<>"")&"×"&TOCOL(A3:A, 1)&"×"&B1:F1&"×"&B2:F2), "×"))


Hi player0, Thank you.
It worked and a good starting point for me. Thank you for directing me to the right question. I was searching the wrong topic, it is data manipulation. I have seen you a lot in the questions that I have looked into. You're really amazing.
Thanks again.
